# How to call another screen in this code below

Tags: c, winapi

Good night, I would like some help with this code below, I have to do an exercise that calls another registration screen, the first screen I managed to assemble, make the buttons work too, but I don't find a practical example on the internet to be able to call this one another screen, I've tried in several ways and without success, I would like some help so to be able to call another screen in this code below. I have to call this other screen there on the Register button, you can see that I've already tried and nothing happens.

```
#define UNICODE
#define _UNICODE
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

const TCHAR CLSNAME[] = TEXT("helloworldWClass");
LRESULT CALLBACK winproc(HWND hwnd, UINT wm, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp);

void addControls(HWND);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hInstPrev, PSTR cmdline, int cmdshow)
{
    //return MessageBox(NULL, "hello, world", "caption", 0);

    WNDCLASSEX wc = { };
    MSG msg;
    HWND hwnd;

    wc.cbSize        = sizeof (wc);
    wc.style         = 0;
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = winproc;
    wc.cbClsExtra    = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra    = 0;
    wc.hInstance     = hInst;
    wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    //wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) GetStockObject (WHITE_BRUSH);
    wc.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = CLSNAME;
    wc.hIconSm       = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wc)) {
        MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Could not register window class"),
                  NULL, MB_ICONERROR);
        return 0;
    }

    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_LEFT,
                          CLSNAME,
                          _T("Covid-19"),
                          WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                          CW_USEDEFAULT,
                          CW_USEDEFAULT,
                          CW_USEDEFAULT,
                          CW_USEDEFAULT,
                          NULL,
                          NULL,
                          hInst,
                          NULL);
    if (!hwnd) {
        MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Could not create window"), NULL, MB_ICONERROR);
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(hwnd, cmdshow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return msg.wParam;
}

void addControls(HWND hwnd) {

    CreateWindowW(L"Static", L"Login", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 600, 0, 100, 18, hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    CreateWindowW(L"Edit", L"", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 600, 40, 100, 18, hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    CreateWindowW(L"Static", L"Senha", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 600, 80, 100, 18, hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    CreateWindowW(L"Edit", L"", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 600, 120, 100, 18, hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    CreateWindowW(L"Button", L"Login", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 600, 160, 100, 18, hwnd, (HMENU) 1, NULL, NULL);
    CreateWindowW(L"Button", L"Cadastrar", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 600, 200, 100, 18, hwnd, (HMENU) 2, NULL, NULL);

}

LRESULT CALLBACK winproc(HWND hwnd, UINT wm, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp) {

    HWND hwndCadastrar;

    switch (wm) {
        case WM_CREATE:
            addControls(hwnd);
            break;
        case WM_CLOSE:
            DestroyWindow(hwnd);
            break;
        case WM_COMMAND:
            if (LOWORD(wp) == 1) {

                hwndCadastrar = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_LEFT,
                                      CLSNAME,
                                      _T("Covid-19 - Cadastrar - Paciente"),
                                      WS_CHILDWINDOW,
                                      CW_USEDEFAULT,
                                      CW_USEDEFAULT,
                                      CW_USEDEFAULT,
                                      CW_USEDEFAULT,
                                      NULL,
                                      NULL,
                                      hwnd,
                                      NULL);

                ShowWindow(hwndCadastrar, SW_SHOW);
                SetForegroundWindow(hwndCadastrar);
                SetFocus(hwndCadastrar);

                Window(hwnd);

                MessageBox(0, (LPCWSTR)L"Login Efetuado Com Sucesso", (LPCWSTR)L"Login", 0);
            } else if (LOWORD(wp) == 2) {
                MessageBox(0, (LPCWSTR)L"Cadastro Efetuado Com Sucesso", (LPCWSTR)L"Cadastrar", 0);
            }
            break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, wm, wp, lp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this C or C++ that you're writing? Please remove the irrelevant tag; they are two separate languages.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo To be fair, Win32 code _really is_ a chimera of macro-laden C89 that has to be compiled by a C++ compiler (Visual Studio is not a C compiler, after all). The 1990s hayday of Win32 was when C++ was more like a proper superset of C - this was before C99 ofc.

Comment: @Dai: That's not true. Pure WinAPI code can be compiled with a C compiler. The vast majority of the documentation for the WinAPI uses straight C code. And tag spamming by using both C and C++ tags is inappropriate - the OP should know what language they are using and tag accordingly. If they don't know, they need to step away from the keyboard until they figure it out.

Comment: @Dai: Point taken. :-) I did say *vast majority* and not all...

Comment: @Dai Visual Studio actually comes with both a C and C++ compiler. You toggle the C compiler on either by using source files with a *.c* extension or one of the [`/Tc` and `/TC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/tc-tp-tc-tp-specify-source-file-type) compiler options.

Comment: Your second window does not give it the WS_CHILDWINDOW style.

Comment: Anyway, *"something is wrong"* is not a problem statement. Please see [ask].

Comment: I'm using the C language, is there any example you saw that I tried to call there when it calls on the button? he passes by and nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

The child window failed to create.

1. You cannot pass a HWND to a HINSTANCE parameter.([argument of type HWND is incompatible with parameter of type HINSTANCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createwindowexw))
2. You cannot create a top-level child window([ERROR_TLW_WITH_WSCHILD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--1300-1699-)).
3. **CW_USEDEFAULT** is valid only for overlapped windows; if **CW_USEDEFAULT** is specified for a **pop-up or child** window, the nWidth and nHeight parameter are set to zero.
4. If you want to see the child window caption, add **WS_CAPTION**.

Finally, the code looks like this:

```
hwndCadastrar = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_LEFT,
                CLSNAME,
                _T("Covid-19 - Cadastrar - Paciente"),
                WS_CAPTION |WS_CHILDWINDOW,
                CW_USEDEFAULT,
                CW_USEDEFAULT,
                1000,
                1000,
                hwnd,
                NULL,
                GetModuleHandle(NULL),
                NULL);
```

For more information about child windows, see [Creating, Enumerating, and Sizing Child Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/using-windows#creating-enumerating-and-sizing-child-windows)